# Permission denied despite being in group that owns the directory

Tags: permissions, ssh, raspberrypi, groups

I have an directory to which I've set the permissions as follow:

```
sudo chown -R root:www-users /var/www
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +
```

My `www-users` group was created this way:

```
groupadd www-users
usermod -a -G www-users pi
usermod -a -G www-users www-data
```

When I type `groups pi` I get:

```
pi : pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio www-data 
video plugdev games users input netdev spi i2c gpio www-users
```

And the `ls -l` inside `/var/www/` gives me:

```
total 4
drwxrwsr-x 8 root www-users 4096 May  8 19:18 html
```

Now, when I log in with my FTP client as `pi` or with ssh, I got `permissions denied` when I try to do:

touch /var/www/html/test.php

Comment: Why 2775? The 2 is sticky bit .. read up on it as this will be the reason ;-) https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/02/sticky-bit/ "A Sticky bit is a permission bit that is set on a file or a directory that lets only the owner of the file/directory or the root user to delete or rename the file. No other user is given privileges to delete the file created by some other user."

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the directories to 0775 and see if that solves the problem, it might be that the setuid bit is the problem.  These permissions work for me.

Answer (score 0):

1 - you have set this to be owned by root. Why not use www-data:www-data?

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www
```

2 - you should be logging into ssh as root or at least be able to use sudo.

```
sudo touch /var/www/test.php
```